how do i backout old changelist from p4v with command
how do i backout old changelist from p4v with command?
old changelist histroy :
file delete #6
file edit #5
file edit #4
file add #3
file delete #2
file add #1

I want to backout file add #3, how to do it with command?
if use https://portal.perforce.com/s/article/3474,
use the following steps:
Change 1000 by trudi@spice on 1999/07/27 11:47:0
Affected files ...
... //depot/foo.txt#1 add
... //depot/bar.txt#3 delete
... //depot/ola.txt#4 edit

p4 sync @999
p4 edit //depot/ola.txt
p4 add //depot/bar.txt
p4 sync @1000
p4 resolve -ay
p4 sync
p4 resolve
p4 delete //depot/foo.txt
p4 submit

it seems not right.

I'm sure you've figured this out by now, but why not just do a delete of the file you added now (p4 delete //depot/file_you_do_not_want.xyz) ?
